# How do I find if a git SHA points to a branch HEAD?

Tags: git

To avoid unnecessarily detached HEADs when checking out a certain git SHA with a (python) script, I'd like to check out a branch instead, if that SHA happens to be the current HEAD of a branch.

Ideally, I want to feed git an SHA, and it returns a branch name if the SHA is on a branch's current tip, or error out if not.

`git describe --all --exact-match <SHA>` *very nearly* is what I need, only that it is primarily aimed at tags, and so if a branch *and* a tag point at my SHA (which often happens in our release branches, for example), only the tag is given. This is not useful, because checking out the tag leads to a detached HEAD (even if a branch points at the same SHA).

Note, I don't want to do `git branch --contains` - I don't need to know which branches *contain* my commit.

If there's no command like `git describe`, just for branches, I know I can cross-check my SHA against branch SHAs via `git show-ref`. That's not the most elegant solution, though.

I could also do `git name-rev --name-only <hash>`, but I'd have to manually check the output for `~` characters, which feels unelegant if there's a git command somewhere to do the same thing.

Comment: With git 2.7 (Q4 2015), `git for-each-ref --points-at <branch_name>` will be possible. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32988371/6309)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the upcoming git 2.7 (Q4 2015) you will get a more complete version of [`git for-each-ref`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref), which now support the `--points-at`

```
git for-each-ref --points-at <branch_name>
```

With the doc:

```
--points-at <object>:
```

> Only list refs which points at the given object.

That will allow to check if a commit is part of that list or not.

---

See [commit 4a71109](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a71109aa442ba1a7045d36f6b148113c95ffc48), [commit ee2bd06](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee2bd06b0f735a00ce0216ca1d3391b13722d987), [commit f266c91](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f266c9163b34ec55e453d27e1ed246d67ee3ced0), [commit 9d306b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d306b5a6077f026291df3c4a5968eaf95a92417), [commit 7c32834](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c32834813bd6aee5ce5b2c4131d9f34249bc9e3), [commit 35257aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35257aa01203bae74f9fb856fb02c10c4b3836e6), [commit 5afcb90](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5afcb90560586765bf21fb09959a8b4497804639), ..., [commit b2172fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2172fdf702426cb4eba093b5504d0a0e9e59746) (07 Jul 2015), and [commit af83baf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af83bafa4867ba16368e58f36e8311e9591e68f4) (09 Jul 2015) by [Karthik Nayak (`KarthikNayak`)](https://github.com/KarthikNayak).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9958dd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9958dd8685a0a8b3d6ecdd07e35d8ecb22b304a7), 05 Oct 2015)</sup>

> Some features from "`git tag -l`" and "`git branch -l`" have been made
>   available to "`git for-each-ref`" so that eventually the unified
>   implementation can be shared across all three, in a follow-up
>   series or two.

```
* kn/for-each-tag-branch:
  for-each-ref: add '--contains' option
  ref-filter: implement '--contains' option
  parse-options.h: add macros for '--contains' option
  parse-option: rename parse_opt_with_commit()
  for-each-ref: add '--merged' and '--no-merged' options
  ref-filter: implement '--merged' and '--no-merged' options
  ref-filter: add parse_opt_merge_filter()
  for-each-ref: add '--points-at' option
  ref-filter: implement '--points-at' option
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try something like this:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short) %(objectname)" 'refs/heads/' |
    grep SHA1 | cut -d " " -f 1
```

That should give you a list of branches that are currently at the revision `SHA1`.

Comment: This is almost correct, but the pattern should be 'refs/heads/' otherwise branches like 'foo/bar' won't be matched.

Comment: @felipec You're absolutely correct.  I updated my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. That's similar to what I'd do with `git show-ref` or `git name-rev`. Guess I hoped to do this with git only, like `git describe`.

Comment: @Christoph Yeah, it's unfortunate that there isn't a better answer here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use python, this is what I would do:

```
import subprocess

def get_name(target):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'for-each-ref', 'refs/heads/'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in p.stdout:
        sha1, kind, name = line.split()
        if sha1 != target:
            continue
        return name
    return None
```

Another option is to use the power of eval to construct a dictionary:

```
d = '{' + subprocess.check_output(['git', 'for-each-ref', '--python', '--format=%(objectname): %(refname),', 'refs/heads/']) + '}'
name = eval(d)[sha1]
```

Comment: Slightly less complex way (not showing the "kind" entries) would be `git show-ref --heads`.

Comment: Thank you. That's similar to what I'd do with `git show-ref` or `git name-rev`. Guess I hoped to do this with git only, like `git describe`.

Comment: I'll accept this instead of the nearly identical answer by @jszakmeister because it doesn't need pipes (so no `Shell=True` necessary in `subprocess`)

Comment: Yes, I guess `git show-ref --heads` would be simpler and would produce basically the same. The only difference is that if the repository contains invalid refs (refs that point to commits that don't exist), then `git show-refs` would just fail, while `git for-each-ref` would still work.

Comment: Recommend adding a `p.communicate()` before returning to discard any remaining `p.stdout` data and wait for the process.  Not always (maybe not even often) needed, but this makes `get_name()` clean up after itself.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I wanted to know if HEAD pointed to a branch **post-checkout** and then exit 0 if pointing to a branch, or exit non-zero if not pointing to a branch, which is most likely detached HEAD state assuming the checkout succeeded. `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` does this and also returns the name of the branch when pointing to one. Obviously, there's better solutions for what the OP needs, but I wanted to throw this in just in case anyone wanted to make use of the information.

Answer (score 1):

### Get only branch names

To get the branch names referenced by a commit or tag, I came up with this `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  branch-name = !"git for-each-ref --format=\"%(refname:short) %(objectname)\" 'refs/heads/' | sed -En 's/^(\\S+)\\s+'\"$(git rev-parse \"$1\" 2>/dev/null)\"'$/\\1/p' | grep . || { echo \"$1: not a branch\" >&2; false;}
```

Eg:

```
$ git branch-head-name da8ecd90
master
```

**Edge cases:**

- Output is null if commit-ish isn't a branch.
- With no arguments, lists all branch names.

---

Note: the alias without `.gitconfig` string quoting is:

```
branch-name=!git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short) %(objectname)" 'refs/heads/' | sed -En 's/^(\S+)\s+'"$(git rev-parse "$1" 2>/dev/null)"'$/\1/p' | grep . || { echo "$1: not a branch" >&2; false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of solution, maybe not very elegant, but quite reliable: is to list all branches `branch --contains $sha` and then check if `git rev-parse $branch` == `$sha`.

Answer (score 0):

What about grep :

```
grep -R [sha] .git/refs/heads/
```

Or since you are calling it from a python script, why not just create a function that searches through those files, and returns the branch name or exception as you wanted.

Comment: @jszakmeister I think you can just as easily grep `.git/packed-refs` or is it compressed?

Comment: No, `packed-refs` is not compressed.  You could grep it, but your command misses the file.  Plus, you would need a slightly different strategy for pulling out the name of the matching ref (you couldn't use the filename, like in your example above).

Comment: @jszakmeister Yeah, that is understood, you would have to parse the file, but it is a very simple file. It might be easier to just parse the files in the python script the OP mentions then to run commands.

Comment: I have to admit I'd rather work with git commands instead of going bare-bones and grep around in .git/

Comment: Peeking into git innards also runs afoul of future changes, such as when `.git/packed-refs` is eventually compressed, for instance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this to test each branch tip hash against your given $sha:

```
 git branch -a| cut -d " " -f 2,3 | xargs -n 1 git rev-parse | grep $sha
```

or just local

```
git branch | xargs -n 1 git rev-parse | grep $sha
```